# how to use onselectedindexchanged in asp.net (how to enable or disable text box based on dropdown selection)

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<div>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">management</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">cet</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">comedk</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

On SELECTING "management" option "rank text box should be disabled else it should be enabled.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to SO, If you are a new user then please have a look here [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to tag your question properly so that you can receive good answer from that area. In present what you have asked can be sorted out both using JavaScript and Asp.net. For immediate feedback you need to add **what you have tried so far** as it will cut this time for preparing a sample for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use below code:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
        onselectedindexchanged="SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="True" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">management</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">cet</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">comedk</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
protected void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
{
     //DISABLE TEXT BOX
}
else
{
//ENABLE TEXT BOX
}
}
```

Do let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ItemChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">management</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">cet</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">comedk</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

protected void ItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
     //disable text box
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "onselectedindexchanged" event to the dropdown control.
Then disable the textbox when dropdown selected value is 1.

Comment: Also in the else condition you need to enable the textbox.if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
     //disable text box else //enable text box

Answer (score 0):

Try this>>

```html
<div>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_Changed">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">management</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">cet</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">comedk</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
  
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat= "server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
/*Code Behind*/
protected void DropDownList1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
         TextBox1.Enabled = false;
        }
     else
        {
          TextBox1.Enabled = true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a page postback to disable a textbox on change of a dropdown:

```
<div>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">management</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">cet</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">comedk</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">


    document.getElementById("<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>").addEventListener("change", ChangeRankState, false);


    function ChangeRankState() {
        var e = document.getElementById("<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>");

        var ddVal = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        if (ddVal === '1') {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtRank.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtRank.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
        }
    }



</script>
```

This is just an example, you may want to update it to be more flexible but I hope you get the idea.

If you want you can change this line:

```
var ddVal = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

to read:

```
var ddVal = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

and then change:

```
if (ddVal === '1')
```

To

```
if (ddVal === 'management')
```

To compare the visible text rather than the value.

Something to note is that the script should be below the div.  You cant and an Event Listener to a control that is not there :)